# merging multiple columns into one column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like the one shown below:

```
col_1    col_2    col_3       col_4    col_5   col_6
  234.     61.     71.         23       45k     61
  462.     371.    73.         64       70k     66
```

I want to merge col_4, col_5, col_6 such the Dataframe becomes:

```
col_1    col_2    col_3             new_col 
 234.     61.     71.       col_4=23;col_5=45k;col_6=61
 462.     371.    73.       col_4=64;col_5=70k;col_6=66
```

How can I do this? The above Dataframe is an example. I have last 50 columns to merge like in **new_col**. Insights will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dictioanry comprehension with `f-string`s:

```
cols = ['col_4','col_5','col_6']

f = lambda x: ';'.join(f'{k}={v}' for k, v in x.items())
df['columns_combined'] = df[cols].apply(f, axis=1)

df = df.drop(cols, axis=1)

print (df)
   col_1  col_2  col_3  columns_combined
0  234.0   61.0   71.0  col_4=23;col_5=45k;col_6=61
1  462.0  371.0   73.0  col_4=64;col_5=70k;col_6=66
```

Comment: But this doesn't remove col_4,col_5,col_6. I want those columns removed as well from the dataframe

Comment: @John - thank you, added `df = df.drop(cols, axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
df['new_col'] = df[df.columns[4:]].apply(
    lambda x: ';'.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),
    axis=1
)
```